# List<int> parameter default binding from url parameter behavour

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Why do we have this behavour?

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult TestProc(List<int> list)
{
  return new ContentResult();
}
```

Request:

/TestProc 
  leads to a null list. OK

/TestProc?list=[]
  leads to an empty list. OK

/TestProc?list=
   leads to a list with one item, 0. Not OK. I assume that the binder sees the query string is present, it has no value hence it pushes the default int value in the list, i.e. it treats list= as the same with list=0. I find this confusing. I would have thought that list= is the same with no list at all in this context and I expected list to be null.

Answer (score 0):

> I find this confusing

I agree. You could use a nullable integer in this situation:

```
public ActionResult TestProc(List<int?> list)
```

This time the model binder will push one element which is `null` and you will be able to disambiguate between `/TestProc?list=` and `/TestProc?list=0` if you had to.

Comment: Yea, you could even argue that any time (unless there is an exception) a model binder sees an empty value for non-nullable type, it should treat it the same as having an invalid character. But I guess if you take into consideration the behavior of an integer, it can be expected behavior. Since ?list=0&list=1 would bind to list = {0, 1}